# Refresh AppWidget with network request using RemoteView button

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

tl;dr question:

> How to properly refresh widget e.g. every minute making network request in background, reliably working Android 5-13 and according to policy

I have an app widget which needs to be refreshed more often than forced `updatePeriodMillis` and also should provide self-refresh button. Self interval refreshing is made with `AlarmManager` and works pretty good and under button click I have same `PendingIntent`:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(REPORT_WIDGET_RUN_UPDATE);
    intent.setClass(context, ReportAppWidgetProvider.class);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

On providers side `onReceive` gets called in both cases and I should do some network now. I'm using Volley, so its trivial, but with `context` passed to `onReceive` I'm always getting timeouts...

Few year ago I've started to use `Service` for this purpose, but starting Android 8 `ForegroundService` must be used for such case (background work, not running any `Activity`). I didn't wanted to show "auto-disappearing" notification to often, so I've switched to `JobIntentService`. It has some [nasty rare bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63622293) and it's deprecated now, so even if it works pretty good I've decided to move on to `WorkManager` as suggesting last post under link, also official doc or some articles (e.g. [this](https://www.ackee.agency/blog/how-to-reliably-refresh-widgets)).

So now my `JobIntentService` becomes `Worker` followed by [this](https://medium.com/tech-takeaways/how-to-migrate-the-deprecated-jobintentservice-a0071a7957ed) article, `Context` in workers contructor works with Volley, network connection is done, feedback-broadcast is sent to provider and... After whole operation I'm getting VERY unwanted system-called `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE`. It's not mine action and it breaks my flow!

In Android 13 I see some suggestion in system logs why I'm getting this call

```
I/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: App widget created with id: 33
I/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: App widget with id: 33 loaded
```

So my widget after such refresh operation gets "recreated"... Behavior is exacly same on Android 10, but without above/any logs (different launcher)

My question is: how to properly refresh widget with network request in  background, reliably working Android 5-13 and according to policy?

Maybe should I stick with sometimes-appearing `ForegroundService` as starting [13 it will be hidden anyway](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#handle-user-initiated-stop)? As far as I remember there is some few-sec-limit for NOT-showing notification? It would be sufficient for me to make network call and then broadcast response to appwidget provider (call made with 3-4 sec. timeout thrown). Any suggestion, preferably working example appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're running into the known `WorkManager` issue where it "restarts" your widget every time. I originally couldn't figure out what was causing this, but there are several issues reported on Google's Issue Tracker, including [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241076154) that I filed. And the workaround top fix this issue is

> to create a one-time Worker set to 10 years out, (use setInitialDelay)
> and set at least one constraint on it

You can see the code in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603702/in-android-glance-widgets-are-flickering-during-every-update-even-if-there-i)

Comment: quick late night check: holy s**t, it works. let me back to you after a weekend and few tests, but seems to: thanks!

Comment: well, I've got back after hour, this works! posted my fix as separated answer, all credits goes to you

Answer (score 0):

fixed with below code, BIG THANKS to user496854 answer and [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603702/in-android-glance-widgets-are-flickering-during-every-update-even-if-there-i)

```
public class ReportAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.i(ReportAppWidgetProvider.this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "onReceive action " + intent.getAction());
        setUpDummyWorkerForPreventingAppWidgetRestarts(context);
        ...

    }

    // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241076154
    private void setUpDummyWorkerForPreventingAppWidgetRestarts(Context context) {
        OneTimeWorkRequest work = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(AppWidgetDelayedWidgetWorker.class)
                .setInitialDelay(10 * 365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setConstraints(
                        new Constraints.Builder()
                                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                                .build()
                )
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(
                AppWidgetDelayedWidgetWorker.TAG,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                work);
    }
```

I've used `ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE` for keeping only one "infinite instance", as my method is called with every broadcast just-to-be-shure (in fact there are two workers and multiple actions for handling by these)

fun fact: above part is in Java, below is in Kotlin. mark of times :)

```
class AppWidgetDelayedWidgetWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerParams: WorkerParameters,
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "DummyWorker"
    }

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.i("DummyWorker", "doWork")
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```