# Jetpack Glance Widget: update called on app exit

Tags: android, glance-appwidget, glance

I implemented a Glance Widget using

Glance 1.0.0-alpha05 
[GlanceAppWidgetHost](https://github.com/google/glance-experimental-tools/tree/main/appwidget-host) 0.2.2

Using the following provider spec. Notice the updatePeriodMillis = 0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:description="@string/loyalty_card_title"
    android:minWidth="110dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:targetCellWidth="2"
    android:targetCellHeight="2"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/loyalty_card_widget_initial"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/splash_logo"
    tools:targetApi="s" /> <!-- targetCellWidth and -height will be ignored by api < s, which is fine -->
```

Now, every time I close(and perhaps open, too) I see the widget update, which manifests in the initialLayout being shown very briefly, giving a glitch appearance. Nothing regarding the widget data changed. How to prevent this?

Issue looks closely related to [In Android, Glance widgets are "flickering" during every update (even if there is no content change)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603702/in-android-glance-widgets-are-flickering-during-every-update-even-if-there-i)
and associated bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241076154

However, I am unsure if it is reelevant since I do not use WorkManager anywhere in my project.

Comment: By `GlanceAppWidgetHost`, do you [mean `GlanceAppWidget`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/glance/appwidget/GlanceAppWidget) or [perhaps `GlanceAppWidgetReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/glance/appwidget/GlanceAppWidgetReceiver)? I [cannot find anything named `GlanceAppWidgetHost`](https://cs.android.com/search?q=GlanceAppWidgetHost&sq=&ss=androidx).

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that; added.
https://github.com/google/glance-experimental-tools/tree/main/appwidget-host

I don't care much about this dependency, so I could remove it if related to the problem